# AJAX POST group of form variables to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send a group of form parameters over to a PHP script for processing.

I've previously done something like this using `$.post`, but now I'm trying to get it done strictly by using `$.ajax`.

Here is the jQuery click event that is supposed to send all of the variables to the PHP script:

```
$('.searchSubmit').on('click', function()
{
  var searchCriteria = {
      import_bill: $('#import_bill').val(), 
      import_ramp: $('#import_ramp').val(), 
      import_delivery: $('#import_delivery').val(), 
      // few more form parameters
    };

  $.ajax({
    url: 'api/railmbs.php', // process script
    type: 'POST',
    data: searchCriteria, // parameter group above
    dataType: 'html' // had this set to json, but only got fail 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log('fail');
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the PHP script, called railmbs.php:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['searchCriteria']))
  {
    $value = $_POST['searchCriteria'];
    $_SESSION['where'] = "";

    $import_bill = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($value['import_bill']));
    $import_ramp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($value['import_ramp']));
    $import_delivery = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($value['import_delivery']));

    echo $import_bill; // just trying to echo anything at this point
  }
?>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong.  If I `echo` `hello` before the `IF` above, the console will output accordingly.  But I cannot seem to get anything to `echo` from inside the `IF`.

Does anyone see my error?

Comment: Answered your question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the "searchCriteria" variable.

Change this:

```
$('.searchSubmit').on('click', function()
{
  var searchCriteria = {
      import_bill: $('#import_bill').val(), 
      import_ramp: $('#import_ramp').val(), 
      import_delivery: $('#import_delivery').val(), 
      // few more form parameters
    };

  $.ajax({
    url: 'api/railmbs.php', // process script
    type: 'POST',
    data: searchCriteria, // parameter group above
    dataType: 'html' // had this set to json, but only got fail 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log('fail');
    }
  });
});
```

to:

```
$('.searchSubmit').on('click', function()
{
    var data = {

    searchCriteria: {

      import_bill: $('#import_bill').val(), 
      import_ramp: $('#import_ramp').val(), 
      import_delivery: $('#import_delivery').val(), 
      // few more form parameters

     } 

    };

  $.ajax({
    url: 'api/railmbs.php', // process script
    type: 'POST',
    data: data, // parameter group above
    dataType: 'html' // had this set to json, but only got fail 
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      console.log('fail');
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what worked.  Accepting your response and the answer.

Comment: No problem! Happy to have helped :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Why not to use `$("form").serialize()`? It would be much cleaner.
Secondary, you transfer data in root object, so to get you values, check `$_POST` array.
Instead of `$value = $_POST['searchCriteria']` use `$value = $_POST;`.
This PHP code should work:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST))
  {
    $_SESSION['where'] = "";

    $import_bill = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['import_bill']));
    $import_ramp = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['import_ramp']));
    $import_delivery = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, trim($_POST['import_delivery']));

    echo $import_bill; // just trying to echo anything at this point
  }
?>
```

Or modify your js to send data in `searchCriteria` object, like this:

```
  var searchCriteria = {
searchCriteria: {
      import_bill: $('#import_bill').val(), 
      import_ramp: $('#import_ramp').val(), 
      import_delivery: $('#import_delivery').val(), 
      // few more form parameters
    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if you actually send post data using your browser developer tools or typing `var_dump($_POST);` at the beginning of your PHP script.

As far as i can see, you never actually set `searchCriteria` as post variable.

Currently your `$_POST` variable should contain the field `import_bill`, `import_ramp` and so on. Either change your `if` statement or your JavaScript object to `{searchCriteria: {/*Your data here*/}`.

Comment: Good one.  I'll double check real quick.

Comment: I just console.log(searchCriteria) and it appears I am catching the form parameters.